# "Deny from all" not working

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, alias, phpmyadmin

I have made following configuration on httpd.conf. But, any IP still can access PHPMyAdmin URLs/aliases. What have I missed? Is this related with "Alias" directive?

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride none
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Comment: To start with something really obvious: did you restart Apache after changing the config? Because nothing really jumps out as obviously wrong in that snippet. Second since that is only part of your config, be aware of how sections are [merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) and how entries inside the main httpd.conf can be overruled inside VirtualHost sections.

Comment: Of course, I have restarted everytime I change conf and conf.d files. I can do it with `<LocationMatch "/(phpmyadmin|phpMyAdmin|mysqladmin)"> ... </LocationMatch>` with the same rule inside. How can I know if there is affected overruled config?